# Rooted but su says "Permission denied"

Tags: android, su

I have this "old" Lenovo A2107 tablet which I rooted years ago (using a download from http://androidforums.com/threads/a2107-root-mods-and-rom-discussion.661261/, tho running its root.bat script by hand from my GNU/Linux machine) and that worked fine.

Then I passed this tablet to my daughter for a couple years, and now I got it back.

/system/bin/su is still present, still the same date and size, still mode "rwsr-sr-x", still the same firmware (Android 4.0.3) so all looks fine, but when I try to run it from a shell, it just tells me "Permission denied".

Any idea what might be going on?  What I could try to do to track it down?

Comment: Better ask on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: And the phone is still rooted? I mean do you have tried `Root checker`?

Comment: Welll, no, that's the problem: the "su" program doesn't do what it used to do any more.  "RootChecker" bumps into the same problem (and other programs that need root, like the system.apps mover.

Comment: Similar: [Why can't I get root access from shell?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40059/why-cant-i-get-root-access-from-shell)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, for those curious to know, I figured out what it was: the /system/bin/su program either accepts the request as-is (depending on who asks) or passes the request to some other program (Superuser.apk).

As it turns out, I still have /system/bin/su but Superuser.apk was missing.  Luckily, /system/bin/su worked fine from the "adb shell", even though it said "Permission denied" when used from ConnectBot and other terminal emulators. So I used "adb shell" to get root access and manually copied Superuser.apk into /system/apps.

Comment: it may be ok for one device. How to copy superuser.apk when app is being installed on multiple devices?

Comment: Do you mean "copied Superuser.apk into /system/app". Because there is no folder system/apps

Comment: Can't remember exactly and I don't have this device any more, but it was the /system subdirectory where many other `*.apk` are found.

Answer (score 26):

Nowadays [Magisk](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/official-magisk-v7-universal-systemless-t3473445) is commonly used for rooting.

I've found that on my Oneplus 5 (Oxygen OS, Nougat) it was sufficient to go to Magisk Manager app, open superuser permissions screen and toggle Shell (com.android.shell) to resolve the adb su permission denied problem.

Comment: For me, Magisk Manager -> Superuser contained `Perfdum`, which needed to be toggled as directed by this answer. Thank you for pointing me to the right place.

Comment: magisk has no version for android 4.0.3

Comment: When I did this, the correct screen could be found by pressing the shield icon (2nd button from the left) on the bar at the bottom of the app.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW... I had a similar problem ( running 'su' from ADB shell yielded 'permission denied' ), so I'll describe my solution.

For context, I had rebrained my Galaxy Nexus with CyanogenMod.

So, I looked at the system settings, and it contains a 'Superuser' section; in that section's own settings ( small menu ), there is a 'Superuser Access' option, which was set to 'Apps only'. I changed that to 'Apps and ADB', and then I was able to start an ADB shell, and from that shell, I was now allowed to run 'su'. :-)